# Updating system variable to the newest version

Tags: python-3.x, window

I have pycharm installed and I'm using a program cutadapt. So I added this package in my project environment, having the most recent version.

When I type `cutadapt --version` on windows cmd, I get the oldest version. I tried to update the version to the most recent one like this:

```
python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade cutadapt
```

It says "upgrade successful".

However I continue to have the oldest version.

Comment: What is the console output you get when you do the upgrade? Is the upgrade successful?

Comment: yes, it says upgrade successful

Comment: Maybe it is writing the new version in a different folder - can you do some digging to find out if `cutadapt` is running a different copy? The console output of the upgrade may give you some clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to locate from which path `cutadapt` is executed with this command in powershell `where cutadapt`, there is probably 2 versions of your package (one from python2 for example)

You can also run this `python3 -m cutadapt --version`, that should run the latest version.